# why is my arcTween callback not being called during update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use `d3` to render a donut chart component. Below is the render code. The problem is that the `arcTween` callback is not being called after a transition. I am using `_current` as an intermediate value for updating data for this component.

```
const pie = d3
      .pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(d => {
        return d.dataPerc;
      });

    const arcTween = d => {
      const i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = i(0);
      return t => {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    };
    if (this.dataset.length <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    const data1 = pie(this.dataset[0]);
    this.path = this.path.data(data1);

    const that = this;
    this.path
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .each(d => {
        this._current = {
          startAngle: d.endAngle,
          endAngle: d.endAngle,
        };
      })
      .style('fill', d => {
        return d.data.color;
      })

    this.path
      .exit()
      .datum(d => {
        return {
          startAngle: d.endAngle,
          endAngle: d.endAngle,
        };
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween('d', arcTween)
      .remove();

    this.path
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween('d', arcTween);
```

Comment: The callback is executed *during* a transition, not *afterwards*. What is your problem here? What do you expect? Can you set up a working demo?

Comment: I am working on a donut chart and want to support rendering change. Ther e is a working demo but it looks a little different with my above code: https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/OQvJor. Currently the issue is when I click on the `refresh button` the chart is out of shape during transition.